# Openshift combining roles for users

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I am using openshift for deploying my web application. For login, I use openshift oauth api with a service account. 
Right now, I am using the `scope: role:edit:<namespace>` for all users when they login. But, now I want to set their access as per their roles defined in their openshift accounts. 
I tried retrieving user roles, but as I do not have admin access, I cannot view user roles.

Any ideas on how to approach this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

PROGRESS: So I was able to somewhat solve my problem:
Basically, as an admin: I created a clusterrole allowing read access to clusterrolebindings and then added that role to the required user.

```
oc create clusterrole roleget --verb=<verb_list> --resource=<resource_list>

oc adm policy add-role-to-user roleget developer
```

Then if I change the scope in my application to `role:roleget:<namespace>`, I am able to access the rolebindings via rest api

```
 curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H 'Accept: application/json' https://$ENDPOINT/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/$NAMESPACE/rolebindings
```

So now, I am able to separately fulfill my requirements. But now, I need to merge the two scopes together somehow, i.e
`scope:role:edit:<namespace>` and `<scope:role:roleget:namespace>`.

Does anybody has an idea how to do this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by set their "access as per their roles defined in their OpenShift accounts". For some information about adding collaborators to a project and what roles they can have as a user see http://cookbook.openshift.org/projects-and-user-collaboration/how-do-i-allow-another-user-to-work-on-my-project.html

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Hi, thank you for your comment. I have modified my question as the first part was somehow solved.

Comment: Maybe you should explain the requirement you have rather than ask how to get your solution working. What you are saying you are doing sounds very unconventional and begs the question of why are you doing it in the first place. Explain the requirement better and can perhaps explain better ways of achieving it.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton use case is:
**1**. I have X, Y services deployed on openshift. My angular application is also deployed here and is using openshift oauth api for authentication purposes. 
**2**. Now, by default on login I am creating a service account for each user and giving him an access as per scope `scope:role:edit:<namespace>` so that the users can perform CRUD operations on X and Y services as well.
**3**. Now, I want to restrict access for the users as per their openshift rolebindings, so I am trying to access the rights on login and then use it to set a global access variable.

Comment: FWIW, if one uses oauth-proxy (https://github.com/openshift/oauth-proxy), you can enable passing through of the users access token to the application behind, you can then use that in calls to the REST API on behalf of the user. In that case you wouldn't need to create a distinct service account. Obviously, the users have to trust your application as you are effectively giving them the ability to impersonate them and do anything they could on the cluster. You would though need to still add a role for them in that project.

Comment: I would also suggest you look at the ``oc auth`` command and its sub options. Run it with the ``--loglevel 9`` option and see what REST API calls it makes under the covers to work out what it does. They may give you clues as to how you can work out what you want.